# Simple regex question (regex included)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I have these strings in a string stream:

```
"do=whoposted&amp;t=1934067" rel=nofollow>61</A></TD><TD class=alt2 align=middle>5,286</TD></TR><TR><TD id=td_threadstatusicon_1911046 class=alt1><IMG id=thread_statusicon_1911046 border=0 alt="" src="http://url.com/forum/images/statusicon/thread_new.gif"> </TD><TD class=alt2><IMG title=Film border=0 alt=Film src="http://url.com/forum/images/icons/new.png"></TD><TD id=td_threadtitle_1911046 class=alt1 title="http://lulzimg.com/i14/7bd11b.jpg &#10; &#10;Complete name : cool-thread.."><DIV><A id=thread_gotonew_1911046 href="http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-new/"><IMG class=inlineimg title="Go to first new post" border=0 alt="Go to first new post" src="http://url.com/forum/images/buttons/firstnew.gif"></A> [MULTI] <A style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=thread_title_1911046 href="http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-name-1911046/">Cool Topic Name</A> </DIV><DIV class=smallfont><SPAN style="CURSOR: pointer" onclick="window.open('http://url.com/forum/members/u2031889/', '_self')">m3no</SPAN> </DIV></TD><TD class=alt2 title="Replies: 11, Views: 1,554"><DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class=smallfont>Today <SPAN class=time>08:04 AM</SPAN><BR>by <A href="http://url.com/forum/members/u1131830/" rel=nofollow>karetsos</A> <A "
```

Currently I use this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex ( "<A\\s+href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^\\x00]*?)\\s+id=thread_title_(\\S+)</A>" );

MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches ( doc.ToString ( ) );

foreach ( Match match in matches )
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32 ( match.Groups [ 1 ].Value );

    string name = match.Groups [ 3 ].Value;
    string link = match.Groups [ 2 ].Value;

    ...
}
```

But it doesn't match anything.

All I am trying to extract are:

IDs: `942321`, `512147`.

Names: `"Visible Thread Name"`, `"Cool Thread"`

Links: `"http://url.com/forum/f80/new-topic-name-942321"`, `"http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-name-512147"`

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: By default, regexes are case-sensitive (a != A). One possible solution is to pass `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as the second parameter to your Regex constructor.

Comment: Still returns 0 matches.

Comment: There is something wrong with your regex, between 'thread_title_' and '</A>' you should have 2 groups (id and name), but you only have one. You should rebuild it from scratch and go part by part and see when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of issues that I found:

- By default, regexes are case-sensitive (a != A). One possible solution is to pass RegexOptions.IgnoreCase as the second parameter to your Regex constructor.
- `id=thread...` you seem to be missing the opening `"` after `id`
- After matching the id you suddenly stop... don't you want to match the name as well in a third group? I guess your regex should end like this:

  ```
  id=\"thread_title_([0-9]+)\">([^<]+)</a>
  ```
- Oh, and don't close the `a` tag after the href, because the thread_title_id is still inside the tag:

  `href=\"([^\"]*)\">`: remove the `>` at the end
- In addition, remove that strange `[^\\x00]*?` group. What's that good for anyway?
- After capturing the thread_title_id, you need to ignore stuff until the closing `>`, in order to ignore the `style=...` attribute.

---

Full solution (warning, spoiler ahead). The `@"..."` syntax ensures that you don't need to escape backslashes (but you need to escape quotes by double quotes).

```
Regex pattern = new Regex (@"<a\s+href=""([^""]*)""\s+id=""thread_title_([0-9]+)""[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>");
```

---

BTW, for debugging this I used the following tool, which I can recommend and which automatically provides an escaped version:

- http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Thanks, can you please post the full version just so that it's easier to see? I mean just the escaped version if possible.

Comment: I tried this with IgnoreCase but didn't work either: "<a\\s+href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^\\x00]*?)\\s+id=\"thread_title_([0-9]+)\">([^<]+)</a>"

Comment: @Joan: No, I won't post the full solution, since it would encourage you to just copy&paste it without fully understanding the regex. ... OK, just kidding, here it is. :-) See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating, this is really strange. I get different output than IE's view source shows me. I will have to get a new sample and see how different it is.

Comment: @Joan: PS: For parsing "real" HTML, using a HTML parser is usually a better solution than regex. Consider, for example, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Oh I never used that before. I will check it out. But for this case, sorry the output I was gettign from webbrowser control was different. I updated the question that shows the actual string I am parsing. Do you know if I can modify your regex to parse that?

Comment: @Joan: What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Heinzi, I made another question that describes it better and shows the actual sample. Didn't realize IE's output was different. So if you take a look at that one, and the link I posted under Kim's answer, you could see a bigger sample. Everything I have tried from here and there just doesn't match all the matches, just 1. I don't know why. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

This returns what you need. No need to be overly strict here:

```
<a.+href=".*topic\-name\-(\S+)\/.+thread_title_(\S+)"
```

Comment: Thanks, btw can you please post the escaped version? I am not sure which characters to escape other than quotes.

Comment: you can put an @ in front of your string, indicating to take it literal, and disabling escape characters (except for double quotes of course). This is used a lot in paths, where there's a lot of backslashes: string aRegex = @"<a.+href=\".*topic\-name\-(\S+)\/.+thread_title_(\S+)\""

Comment: Thanks will try it when I get back home :O